# php exec doesn't work for ping on server

Tags: php, arrays, server, exec, ping

I'm trying to ping an IP with exec function to know if IP gets pinged or not, it works totally fine on localhost and returns the output array, but when I run it on the server it returns an empty output array.

when exec works it returns an array as $output and return variable as $return_var.

if ping's unsuccessful, so when IP can't be pinged, it returns:

> array: with 9 elements
>
> return_var: 1

if IP is pinged it returns:

> array: with more than 9 elements
>
> return_var: 0

on server it returns:

> empty array
>
> return_var: 2

as I searched and found out when return_var is 2, it means that exec doesn't work and there's an error.

this is my code:

```
 <?php
    exec('ping -n 4 '.$ip, $output, $return_var);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($output);
    ?>
```

exec() isn't disabled on server, I tried this:

```
<?php
$disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($disabled);
?>
```

and this is a disabled functions list I got:

```
 array(8) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "symlink"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "proc_close"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "proc_open"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "popen"
      [4]=>
      string(6) "system"
      [5]=>
      string(2) "dl"
      [6]=>
      string(8) "passthru"
      [7]=>
      string(14) "escapeshellcmd"
    }
```

is there any chance any of these blocked functions causing problems of exec() functionality ?

also safe mode is OFF on server and it runs php version 5.3.29

Comment: 1. is `ping` _really_ an executable on "the server"? Is it _really_ in the path defined for the http server process? 2. what does your error log file reveal? 3. have you checked what a return value `2` actually means? IIRC, then it means that packages were sent, but no answer whatsoever could be received. That would mean that you face a networking issue, probably a firewall blocking ICPM packages, which is quite common, actually.

Comment: If it concerns linux, you should give the amount of pings to do. Otherwise it will keep pinging without returning output.

Comment: I have error_reporting(E_ALL); on the top of my file and it returns nothing, there's no any error displayed.

Comment: In addition to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to view errors.

Comment: added ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); and there's no any error displayed again.

and ping's executable on the server.

Comment: try: SYSTEM, or Passthru

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I thought all servers where running windows, but the one my site is up to is running unix, and exec needed a little change:

on windows it's:

```
exec('ping -n 4 '.$ip, $output, $return_var);
```

and on unix, it's:

```
exec('ping -c 4 '.$ip, $output, $return_var);
```

but new problem is that, it doesn't ping the ips that actually gets pinged but can't be found on ns_lookup in cmd. some of these ips gets pinged and some not. on localhost it works fine.